# socket() function from nacl sdk returns -1

Tags: c, sockets, google-nativeclient

I have build chrome app with nacl module which calls `socket()` function, but the function returns -1. I have compiled the module with -lnacl_io linker option. Also I have tried to run Goolgle Chrome with `--allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost`. I call this function with the next arguments:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

Why is this function failed?

Comment: You clearly haven't done your homework. First of all, you need to know why it returned `-1` by inspecting the value of `errno` after the call to `socket()`.

Comment: `socket` is a UNIX system call, not really anything to do with google-nativeclient

Comment: errno returns 38(Function not implemented). Can I use socket's POSIX API of native client?

Comment: @RomanSushinskiy now you have your answer.

Comment: self, does nacl sdk have analog functions for working with sockets?

Comment: @RomanSushinskiy You really MUST read the documentation.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network

Comment: jxh, yes, permission section had been added, but it does not help
  "permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "read"]},
    "alarms",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    {"sockets": {
                "tcp": { "connect" : "*:*" },
                "udp": { "connect" : "*:*" },
                "tcpServer": { "listen" : ":*" }
            }}
  ],

Comment: ihabor, I have red the documentation. It says that nacl_io supports POSIX sockets 
https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/nacl_io

Comment: Please add all the information of what you have tried to get it to work.

Comment: What version of the NaCl SDK are you using? Have you tried running the nacl_io_demo example? You can try using sockets there (the connect button).

Comment: Thanks to all, I've fixed this problem. I'd forgotten to call nacl_io_init_ppapi function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to call nacl_io_init_ppapi function